# Using a date value as a key in a bash associative array

Tags: bash, date

I've got a date value and an associated integer which I want to store in an array via my bash script. For the moment I'll just put the offending lines as I think the issue is localised.

```
chartDate=2014-12-01;
dayTotal=5;

dataArray[${chartDate}]=$dayTotal;
```

When attempting the above I get:

`line 125: 2014-12-01: value too great for base (error token is "01")`

I get different errors if I attempt either of the below:

```
dataArray["${chartDate}"]=$dayTotal;
dataArray[\""${chartDate}"\"]=$dayTotal;
```

Any suggestions?

The full script is:

```
function getChartData () {


    chartDate=$(chartStartsAt); #$(chartStartAt) returns a date formatted %Y-%m-%d
    echo $chartDate;

    now=`date +%Y-%m-%d`;
    echo $now;

    issueCount=`jq '. | length'  output/json/FullIssueList.json`; #returns an integer

    declare -a dataArray;

    while [ "${chartDate}" \< "${now}" ]
        do 
            #increment chartDate by one day
            chartDate=$(date -j -v +1d -f "%Y-%m-%d" "${chartDate}" +%Y-%m-%d);
            echo $chartDate

            #Get number of records that match that date
            dayTotal=`grep -c "${chartDate}" output/json/FullIssueList.json`;
            echo $dayTotal;

            #Put values in the array
            dataArray[${chartDate}]=$dayTotal;
        done

    for K in "${!dataArray[@]}"; do echo $K --- ${MYMAP[$K]}; done

}
```

And here's the -uxv output as suggested in comments, note that theres another 7 or 8 results above this:

```
+ set -uxv
+ dataArray[${chartDate}]=0
+ '[' 2014-12-06 '<' 2015-01-09 ']'
date -j -v +1d -f "%Y-%m-%d" "${chartDate}" +%Y-%m-%d
++ date -j -v +1d -f %Y-%m-%d 2014-12-06 +%Y-%m-%d
+ chartDate=2014-12-07
+ echo 2014-12-07
2014-12-07
grep -c "${chartDate}" output/json/FullIssueList.json
++ grep -c 2014-12-07 output/json/FullIssueList.json
+ dayTotal=0
+ echo 0
0
+ set -uxv
+ dataArray[${chartDate}]=0
+ '[' 2014-12-07 '<' 2015-01-09 ']'
date -j -v +1d -f "%Y-%m-%d" "${chartDate}" +%Y-%m-%d
++ date -j -v +1d -f %Y-%m-%d 2014-12-07 +%Y-%m-%d
+ chartDate=2014-12-08
+ echo 2014-12-08
2014-12-08
grep -c "${chartDate}" output/json/FullIssueList.json
++ grep -c 2014-12-08 output/json/FullIssueList.json
+ dayTotal=0
+ echo 0
0
+ set -uxv
+ dataArray[${chartDate}]=0
./GetJiraReleaseIssues.sh: line 125: 2014-12-08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

Comment: Works fine for me with bash 4.2.8. Output of this line is `5`: `chartDate=2014-12-01; dayTotal=5; dataArray[${chartDate}]=$dayTotal; echo ${dataArray[${chartDate}]}`

Comment: Interesting, that works for me too. It could be that the issue is with the way I'm looping over the dates. I'm going to add more information to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use an associative array, you must first declare it as such

```
declare -A dataArray
#        ^
#    CAPITAL A
```

If you don't do this, bash treats the array as a normal one and tries to interpret the index as a numeric expression.

Comment: @TheMightyLlama: What bash version do you run? It works for me.

Comment: I tried in 3 and just now upgraded to 4. Same issue.

Comment: @TheMightyLlama: Try running the script with `set -uxv`

Comment: @TheMightyLlama `[[ a == A ]] && echo 'Really?'`

Comment: could you be more verbose please?

Comment: That fixed it. It was originally lower case as I was using bash 3. Since my upgrade after I made the post I could have switched. Cheers for spotting that.